# XML to JSON with org.json fails in JUnit test. NoSuchMethodError for JSONObject

Tags: java, junit, org.json

I have a Spring Boot project where i map XML to JSON using org.json. This works very well outside test environment, but when I try to unit test, I get NoSuchMethodError on the first method call on the JSONObject. Looking at other answers at SO, it looks like JSONObject is not available for unit testing by default or something like that.

How can I unittest a class using org.json and JSONObject?

Comment: The error message indicates, that different versions of the library are used for compile and run.

Comment: @Henry yeah I can actually see that the project have 2 different versions of org.json in dependencies. But how do I specify which version to use when running a test?

Comment: Make sure there is just one version in the classpath.

Comment: @Henry That actually work when I changed the version I chose to use, to the one version that another dependency dragged into the project. Only problem with this, is that I had to use a older version of org.json which dident have a method I was using from the newer version, thus failing again.

Comment: Actaully, there is not much you can do apart from fixing the code so that it works with only one version.

Comment: @Henry Okey,Thanks anyway! I will try adjusting the code to the older version

Comment: @Henry Well, it fixed it! So thanks :)

Answer (score -2):

The class is available, but it's of different version and thus misses some of the methods that other libs require.

Use `<dependencyManagement>` in your root pom.xml to specify the version of the lib that you want to use across the project. Then you can remove the versions in the sub-modules because the defaults will be taken from the `<dependencyManagement>`.